Referring to the branch of the current working directory with unstaged changes as a branch
It is often useful to use the HEAD keyword in git commands to refer to the last commit of the active branch.
What I am curious about is whether there is such a keyword for the working directory, which includes possible modification on top of HEAD, like unstaged changes (without having to commit these changes, obviously).
For example, I often like to view the difference between two branches using git difftool BRANCH BRANCH2, where I know that the order of BRANCH, BRANCH2 that I put in that command will point my diff tool to whether I should look left or right of the difftool GUI to see the changes in a specified branch (in the order I specified).
That is why I would see the usefulness of heaving such a "WORKING_DIRECTORY_HEAD".
Is there such a thing, or something similar that would fit my needs?
I realize that doing git difftool BRANCH (specifying only one branch) would actually do exactly what I want (comparing BRANCH to the WORKING_DIRECTORY_HEAD), but I just always forget the order it uses and which changeset is on the right or the left of the GUI in this case, so I would rather prefer if I had a keyword to refer to that WORKING_DIRECTORY_HEAD so I can specify the order on my own.

Whilst HEAD refers to the last commit, there isn't a specific keyword for the working directory with unstaged changes. May you provide an example of a git difftool command where a WORKING_DIRECTORY_HEAD keyword would be helpful?

HEAD isn’t just a keyword. It’s a concrete thing. The index/staged changes is also a concrete thing although I haven’t seen a shorthand for it. In fact that’s perhaps the most inconsistent thing out of three three: index/stage/cache. Unstaged changes have not been put into Git at all. In turn there is no concrete thing to point to. To my knowledge.

@evolutionxbox Well, off the top of my head it could be helpful instead of doing git difftool HEAD where I would like to have control where the unstaged changes appear - left or right pane (and to be honest, I always seem to forget where each goes when using the former command)

(in my perfect world you would be able to use git(1) with option arguments only (--option style) since I always get confused about at least some of the positional arguments—not to mention the positional arguments that give you “ambigious” errors without a pathspec)

Unstaged changes, or staged but uncommitted do not belong to any branch. They are in the working tree and in cache/index. There is no reference in Git to name them.

I don't think there's a commit-ish way to specify "my dirty working tree". The possibilities are described in git help revisions.
However, you can control which side of the diff is which even without that, just using
git diff HEAD

or
git diff -R HEAD

